# How can this be an optimal strategy?

Tags: matrices, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I'm following a course on Game Theory and I'm trying to understand the following exercise:

*Consider the game with game matrix*

$$
G = \begin{pmatrix}-2 & 2 & -1\\1&1&1\\3&0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
*Show that player II has an optimal strategy giving positive weight to each of each of his columns.*

There are two players in this game, player I and player II. Each element $G(i,j)$ in the game matrix resembles the payoff to player I if player I chooses strategy $i$ and player II chooses strategy $j$.

The correct solution is apparently that player II has the optimal mixed strategy $(1/4, 1/2, 1/4)$. When I asked my teacher why this is the case and how you can find such a solution, he told me that since $(1,0,0), (1/2, 1/2, 0)$, and $(0,0,1)$ are optimal strategies for player II, and since the convex combination of optimal strategies is also optimal, we can take

$$
1/3*(1, 0,0) + 1/3 * (1/2, 1/2, 0) + 1/3*(0,0,1) = (1/4, 1/2, 1/4)
$$
such that $(1/4, 1/2, 1/4)$ is again an optimal strategy for player II.

**My question is:** Why are $(1,0,0)$ and $ (1/2,1/2,0)$ optimal strategies for player II?

What I don't get is how for example $(1,0,0)$ could be an optimal strategy for player II. If I understand the concept of optimal strategies correctly, an optimal strategy should guarantee a player at least the value of the game, no matter what the other player does (I believe this is called the principle of indifference, player X looks for a strategy that makes player Y indifferent).

If player II plays $(1,0,0)$, and player I plays $(0,1/2,1/2)$, the expected payoff for player II is $1/2 * 1 + 1/2 * 3 = 2$ which is higher than the value of the game. So how can this be an optimal strategy?

Comment: Is it a zero sum game? You say at the start of the question that the matrix gives the payoff to player I, but in the last paragraph you treat the values as payoffs to player II.

Comment: Yes it is., The payoffs are defined as the amount that player II has to player I. When I say that the expected payoff for player II is 2, this means that player II has to pay 2 to player I.

Comment: I think the correct way of phrasing that would be "*payout by*" instead of "*payoff for*".

Answer (score 1):

You're quite right that $(1, 0, 0)$ and $(\tfrac12, \tfrac12, 0)$ are not optimal strategies for player II. The value of the game is $1$ to player I, so if the probabilities of player II's mixed strategy are $p,q,(1-p-q)$ then $$-2p + 2q - (1-p-q) \le 1 \\
p + q + (1-p-q) \le 1 \\
3p + (1-p-q) \le 1$$
The second inequality is, of course, trivial.
The other two rearrange to $$-p + 3q \le 2 \\
2p - q \le 0$$
The algorithmic way to find a solution with three non-zero weights would be to add the constraints $p \ge \varepsilon$, $q \ge \varepsilon$, $p + q \le 1 - \varepsilon$, and try small values of $\varepsilon$ (e.g. $\varepsilon = 10^{-n}$) until you find one which gives a consistent set of inequalities.

The quick and dirty approach is to observe that the inequality $-p + 3q \le 2$ certainly holds if $q \le \tfrac23$, the inequality $2p - q \le 0$ is just $p \le \tfrac q2$, and any value of $q$ which is strictly less than $\tfrac23$ therefore implies that $p + q < 1$. The "correct" mixed strategy which you were given is a member of this family of solutions $q < \tfrac23$, $p \le \tfrac q2$, and arguably the simplest member.